# JavaScript inheritance magic

Tags: javascript

When I run this code:

```
function foo() { 
    console.log("foo"); 
    var self = this; 
    this.a = function() { 
        return arguments.length == 0 ? self.b : (self.b = arguments[0]); 
    }; 
}; 
function bar() {
}; 
bar.prototype = new foo(); 
var a = new bar(); 
var b = new bar(); 
console.log(a.a()); 
b.a(true); 
console.log(a.a());
```

I get the following output: `foo, undefined, true`

What I do not understand is how the object returned by the constructor function `foo` somehow manages to allocate a new memory location for `b`. I was totally expecting the last output to be `true` because I only get 1 `foo` output.

That this works is great, but it feels too much like magic.

My problem really here is that I'd like to setup an initialization order (or chain). What I've realized is that `foo` cannot take any arguments, because it's only called once, to provide a base (or template of sorts).

I'd like to devise a really simple schema where `foo` has parameters that has to be passed from `bar` to `foo` (because `bar` inherits `foo`). I'm fine with something like calling `foo.apply(this, arguments)` from `bar` but the call to set the prototype has to be done without arguments, what I need is a fluent way to somehow tell the two apart.

But I really don't want to build an entire service around creating objects that allow some kind of inheritance, the only thing I really care about is constructing the objects, correctly...

Comment: I get logged `foo, undefined, true`. The last `undefined` does show up in Chrome Developer Tools but that's just the return value of `console.log`. You only have 3 logs anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, I just copied from output from the Chrome console, missed that...

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Would you mind not calling member functions and variables the same name?  Me poor reader alreddy haz heddeack...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a side note, you're sometimes using `self` and sometimes using `this`... personally, I'd be more consistent. I like to use `that` because [`this` can be confusing](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) and [`self` is part of the BOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.self),  but it's just a matter of taste.

Try [parasitic inheritance](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html):

```
function foo(arg) {
    var that = this;
    that.a = function() { 
        return arguments.length == 0 ? that.b : (that.b = arguments[0]); 
    };
}

function bar(arg) {
    return new foo(arg);
}

bar.prototype = new foo(); 
var a = new bar();  // the `new` is now optional. Personally I'd remove it...
var b = bar();  // ... like I did here!
console.log(a.a()); 
b.a(true); 
console.log(a.a());
console.log(b.a());
```

... here the inheritance behaves in a more classically, explicitly invoking a parent constructor when the constructor is called.

Comment: I hate "that", it connotes something different from this.  I prefer "instance"

Comment: @George Jempty - Fair enough. I think the important part is to be consistent; don't use `this` and then `self` for example.

Comment: I agree about the consistency.  And I know Crockford uses "that" so I am a bit out on a limb.

Comment: @John Leidegren - Rolled back; I meant "Browser Object Model" - `self` refers to a `window` object, and windows aren't really in scope of the Document Object Model.

Comment: BOM is byte order mark in my vocabulary, pardon the confusion. DOM is the browser model for me, even though the D stands for Document, I don't really make a difference between the window and document object.

Comment: @John Leidegren - Most people don't; I'm just difficult :P

Comment: The reason I use self is actually an homage to the programming language Self, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_(programming_language%29 which influenced the development of JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is one of the weak spots (and yet, strong spots) of JS. You're running into a pattern issue here. I'd suggest taking a look at http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/ - there's a free 'class' you can use to help straighten up what one would expect with a more 'classical' inheritance.

Just as a quick example, most patterns I've seen have a base 'object' (which is more or less a customized class) and the constructor (which is more or less 'how the object gets built') calls something like "this.init.apply(this, arguments)". That calls an 'init' method on the object with all the arguments that have been passed. So the init can then be set, extended, re-set, etc., and the constructor always calls the one that is 'local' to itself with the arguments that have been passed. Pretty neat.

Hope that helps, or at least doesn't confuse.

Answer (score 0):

The last output *is* `true`.  You are being deceived by your JavaScript console.  That last `undefined` is the return value from your expression.  Make your `console.log()` calls more descriptive to shine a light on what's happening:

```
function foo() {  
    console.log("foo constructor called");  
    var self = this;  
    this.a = function() {  
        return arguments.length == 0 ? self.b : (self.b = arguments[0]);  
    };  
}
function bar() { 
}
bar.prototype = new foo();  
var a = new bar();  
var b = new bar();  
console.log("value from a.a(): " + a.a());  
b.a(true);  
console.log("value from a.a(): " + a.a()); 
console.log("done logging");
```

This yields the following output in the console:

```
foo constructor called
value from a.a(): undefined
value from a.a(): true
done logging
undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not magic, it's prototypal inheritance. I think what you're trying to achieve is combining two constructor functions to get called automagically. You're probably mixing up constructors and prototypes.

> But I really don't want to build an entire service around creating
>   objects that allow some kind of inheritance, the only thing I really
>   care about is constructing the objects, correctly...

I don't know what you mean by "service". But as in any other object-oriented programming language, superclass method calls need to be done manually. So either you hard-code the "superclass" like this:

```
function foo() { 
    console.log("foo"); 
    var self = this; 
    this.a = function() { 
        return arguments.length == 0 ? self.b : (self.b = arguments[0]); 
    }; 
}
function bar() {
    foo.apply(this, arguments); // <- ugly
}
//bar.prototype = new foo(); // this is not neccessary
```

...or you build some wrapper stuff to connect your "classes". Something like:

```
function inherit(superconstructor) {
    return function () {
        superconstructor.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
function foo() {...}
bar = inherit(foo);
```